# Install python (scipy)package from MacOS

Tags: python, scipy, conda

I am trying to install a forked version of scipy to my windows machine. The forked version is on macos. So i created a virtuel env in conda. And did `pip install git+https:...`
The fails with the error: `Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

So I tried to download the Repo and do `python setup.py install --user` instead.
This fails with the gfortran error: `unrecognized command-line option '-mno-cygwin': did you mean '-mno-clwb'
error command "...gfortran.exe -wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-secon-underscore -mno-cygwin ....."failed with exit status 1`

I set up the Msys2-Terminal as scipy-repo provides - even openblas-stuff. What am I missing or is there a simpler solution??

`gfortran --version GNU Fortran 10.1.0 by MSYS2`

`make --version GNU make 4.3 built for x86-64-pc-cygwin`

`gcc --verison GNU 10.1.0`

Comment: If I recall correctly, older SciPy releases do not support Python 3.8. I think you have 3 options (maybe more, but these are the 3 I can think of :-)) You can either downgrade your Python, install the `wheel` package first (which fixed this problem in my limited other testing but may not help here), or rebase your custom fork to a newer version of SciPy.

Comment: Thank you - i created a new envs with Python 3.7. Install pip and did the update for setuptools and wheel in it. pip install git+https... now failes with "unicodeDecodeError: "charmap" codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 103...." Any Idea?

Comment: Sorry, not really. It would help to edit the post with the new complete error message

Comment: Can you share the repo/project, or is it private?